# Rails: SQL_NO_CACHE in development for tuning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mysql2

What would be an easy way to make active record use SQL_NO_CACHE with all queries in development environment?

I want to optimize the statements for worst case load time. Hope it makes sense to even do it this way, but I get very slow queries the first page hit and next time all queries are really fast, as the server supposedly caches them.

I am using the mysql2 gem 0.3.11 with rails 3.2.3.

Comment: Are you sure it's the query cache that's helping and not the buffer cache ? Even a well indexed query will be slow the first as mysql needs to read the index from disk

Comment: Not entirely sure. The server has lots of RAM and should hold all indices in memory, if I configure everything right. I guess I meant to say second worst case. When the indices are already loaded, but the specific set of ids I query has not been requested, yet.

Comment: If it's just the query cache you want to hobble, the easiest thing would be to just turn it off in you my.cnf settings

Comment: I added a before filter in my application controller `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SET SESSION query_cache_type = OFF") if Rails.env == "development"`. `RESET QUERY CACHE` would also be an option. Please add an Answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I didn't want to edit hundreds of queries, I placed a before filter in the application controller like this:

```
def disable_sql_query_cache_in_development
  if Rails.env == "development"
    Rails.logger.warn Utils.yellow "ApplicationController.disable_sql_query_cache_in_development", "Query cache will be reset for worst case performance tuning"
    #ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SET SESSION query_cache_type = OFF")
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("RESET QUERY CACHE")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular rails find you can stuff this in:

2.3.5:

```
User.find(:all, :select => "SQL_NO_CACHE *", :conditions=>"id = 1234")
```

3+

```
User.where(:id => 10).select("SQL_NO_CACHE *")
```